# Best way to shorten a URL in javascript *without* a database

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a Java dev that's new to Typescript/Javascript. I have a directive to make my app's URL line shorter by coding up some sort of hash. So instead of:

`https://www.someurl.com?urgency=all&impact=widespread&contentType=mine&...`

I need something like:

`https://www.someurl.com?params=somethingShort`

How is this problem typically solved for in Javascript? I don't have any storage to use, so this will have to be an in-memory solution.

When I look up "hash URL params", I get something about the "#" sign in the location, and I don't think that's my use-case... Can someone point me to a solution??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text compression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6791329/328193)

Comment: a hash is non-reversible by definition. you presumably don't want a hash. you want compression.

Comment: A hash is irreversible, you want compression so that you'll be able to calculate the original URL.

Comment: If you control the server and there aren't too many of these, you could use a .htaccess redirect that maps something like `https://www.someurl.com/report1` to the long URL

Comment: Is `www.someurl.com` a web application under your control? Then change the parameters and values for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical URL shorteners use a database to pair a short ID with the real URL.

Without a database you have to create an algorithm that allows the same data to exist in a shorter form. How you do that is really up to you.

---

The first thought is to gzip the parameters, and then base64 encode that binary data to make it work in a URL. But this probably wont help.

```
urgency=all&impact=widespread&contentType=mine
```

Gets gzipped and then base64 encoded as

```
eNorLUpPzUuutE3MyVHLzC1ITC6xLc9MSS0uKEpNTFFLzs8rSc0rCaksSLXNzcxLBQCqJxIm
```

(see https://bugdays.com/gzip-base64)

There's just not a lot of repetition in that, and using base64 encoding adds extra bytes.

So this is not a general problem. It is a specific problem that will most likely be solved in a way that is specific to your application.

---

A better option is to create a compressed encoding yourself.

For example, you could define a compressed format that has a single letter for each value you want to pass in a specific order.

```
urgency=all&impact=widespread&contentType=image/jpg
```

Could encode as:

```
awj
```

Where:

- `a` at position `0` expands to `urgency=all`
- `w` at position `1` expands to `impact=widespread`
- `j` at position `2` expands to `contentType=image/jpeg`

You then write an `encode()` / `decode()` function for that format that works the real data you want in your application.

---

What format you choose is up to you and what data is being encoded. Are these all "one of a finite list of values" kind of parameters (i.e. all or none)? Or are there numeric parameters? Free text strings of unknown length?

The more you can make assumptions about your data, the more you can compress it down. You'll just have to come with an encoding scheme that works for what your data is.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a directive to make my app's URL line shorter by coding up some sort of **hash**. So instead of:

A hash is irreversible, so you cannot use a hash to shorten your URLs without resorting to storage.

> How is this problem typically solved for in Javascript?

I don't think this is a "typical" problem for JavaScript and I can tell you it has nothing to do with JavaScript itself.

This is because you want to use compression, which is a language agnostic problem.

However, I don't think compression will do much for shortening the URLs (depending on the input characteristics of the URL, this might be a different story).

Instead of using compression, I highly suggest you use storage since then you'll be able to use hashes.

If you insist on using compression, search the internet for a suitable (depending on your needs) compression algorithm, then find an implementation of that algorithm in JavaScript (should't be too hard for popular compression algorithms).

Last resort would be to develop your own compression algorithm, but since you're asking this pretty basic question here, I highly doubt you have the skill required to do that.

Comment: I appreciate your extensive explanation, thanks. I think the dig at the end was unnecessary though - I know my limitations already.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. If you feel offended by it, then I'm sorry - that wasn't the point. I'm sure you do know your limitations, but I like to be exhaustive if I can. There are other people that read these questions too, so not everything someone writes in an answer is directed at you specifically.

Comment: @Marco, you can't assume someone's skill level so easily in my experience. And yeah, it sure seems like an unnecessary dig to me as well. For the principle of charity, I'd recommend you edit that part out of your answer.

Comment: @AlexWayne _"you can't assume someone's skill level so easily in my experience."_ no you cannot. But you can presume a lot of someone's experience alone by looking at how a particular question is asked. OP doesn't know what a hash is, OP doesn't know that this problem is not specific to JavaScript etc. If you feel offended by my statement, then that's your thing. I'm not going to edit my post.

Comment: Programming can be a daunting task to beginners that may read this answer in the future. Condescension about their skill level will not help them be better in this craft. It may scare them away instead. Adding "don't take it personally" after "you suck" doesn't really make it any better.

Comment: @AlexWayne Let it go. I never said anything remotely to _"you suck"_. I said what I said so that OP can go to the person that "directed" them to do that task to tell them that this is not an easy problem to solve (**if** you want a general solution, which is always _preferred_), OP hasn't been specific enough to rule a general solution out. [...]

Comment: [...] and it happens to be that a general solution is _always_ better than a specialized one (in terms of usability, maintainability, re-usability etc.). If OP had the knowledge of that, OP wouldn't be posting here saying they were "directed" to do something that's clearly hard to do. Learn to respect other people's opinion and move on. I can't believe you two make such a big deal of a simple sentence telling them what they're trying to do is _hard_. Programming _is_ _hard_ that's just the reality of it. Let it go, I won't respond to further comments.

Answer (score 0):

There could be confusion on what you mean by "hash". As hash could represent a  fragment identifier in the URL, usually represented by the # like #fragmentName.

For my answer, I'm using a javascript map to store the full data that you would need, but you can use a basic object also.

This will allow you to get a URL parameter called **keyID** which you can always change. The URL format would be something like: https://example.com/?keyID=test1

Then we check for that key to exist in our data map and if it does, you have data to use for that page.

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
//const keyID = urlParams.get('keyID'); //actually use this line
const keyID = "test1"; //for testing

let data = new Map();
data.set("test1",{"urgency" : "all","impact" : "widespread","contentType":"mine"});

let pageData;

if(data.has(keyID)){
  pageData = data.get(keyID);
}

console.log(pageData)
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient since it requires the client to download all possible URL shortenings available. Depending on the nature of the shortened URLs, this also could be a potential privacy concern. If OP needs "shorter" URLs, then OP might as well just change the query parameters to something more concise.